# Ngrok service always starts with its inspection database disabled

Tags: ngrok

This pertains to running ngrok as a [background service](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/installing-as-a-service/) in launchd on macOS. Following the directions, I installed the service:

```bash
ngrok service install --config /opt/homebrew/etc/ngrok/config.yml
```

Then started it:

```bash
ngrok service start
```

However, the log output states that `inspect: true` is being ignored because the inspection database is disabled:

```
INFO[05-08|10:13:12] open config file                         path=/opt/homebrew/etc/ngrok/config.yml err=nil
WARN[05-08|10:13:12] ignoring inspect: true because inspection database is disabled name=<snip>
```

According to their [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/config/#inspect_db_size) for the agent configuration file, it seems like the inspection database is disabled when the value for `inspect_db_size` is `-1`. This defaults to `0` which actually means the size is capped at 50MB. Maybe I need to force this to be enabled? So I explicitly added the related values to the configuration file:

```yaml
version: "2"

authtoken: <snip>

api_key: <snip>

# 100 MB
inspect_db_size: 104857600

tunnels:
  nameofmytunnel:
    proto: http
    addr: 3000
    inspect: true
```

After restarting the service with the updated configuration file, I keep seeing the same log output about the disabled inspection database. Also, visiting the web UI at http://localhost:4040/status, the "Inspect" status is labeled as "disabled."

Is there another configuration I'm overlooking that keeps disabling the inspection database? When I run `ngrok http 3000` and keep ngrok running in the foreground of a terminal session, the status page shows "Inspect" as "enabled." I would like to have this enabled when running in launchd.

The version of ngrok I'm running is 3.2.2.

Comment: In case you are trying to monitor the connections using ngrok inspect, you can also try https://pinggy.io , no need to install anything with that for using the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behaviour in my workspace. After search over all internet, I decided to make a workaround and it works for me (Ubuntu 22).

1. Edit the "/etc/systemd/system/ngrok.service"
2. Comment the following line:

```
    #ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ngrok "service" "run" "--config" "/home/vagrant/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml"
```

3. Replace for this one:

```
    ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ngrok "start" "--all" "--config" "/home/vagrant/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml"
```

4. Type this command:

```
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

5. Start the service:

```
    sudo systemctl start ngrok
```

I don´t know how to do that on Mac OS. But I could suppose that are something similar .

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for this – worked for me (on macOS).

On macOS: the service file lives at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/ngrok.plist` (e.g. to edit in Terminal: `sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/ngrok.plist`). The file is XML / Apple's Property List format, and contains the same text to replace as your instructions here (`service` => `start`, `run` => `--all`)

Comment: Oh, and: regarding restarting the service after editing its configuration: I used ngrok's built-in `ngrok service restart` command.

Comment: Any solution for Windows 10/11? If I change the path of the service to "start -all ..." the service wont start.